# Blur Effect in iOS8

Tags: ios, view

I am trying to create blur effect on the UIView as well as I want to add vibrancy Effect so that I can highlight my buttons and use them. I am trying to learn via apple docs and couple of tutorials but unable to get in the following steps I am doing are correct.

Steps 1. I am creating a blur view adding it as subview to present view so that it looks blur.
Step 2 . Then i am creating a vibrancy view for the blur effect and adding it to contentview of blurview.

But i am unable to get the blur effect, can anyone help me to understand 
1. If the following steps are correct. 
2. If not how should ideally the sequence be.
3. How to highlight those buttons and use them. ( I am attaching the snaphot of my storyboard too).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   UIBlurEffect *blurEffect= [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
   UIVisualEffectView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
   [blurView setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
   [self.view addSubview:blurView];


    UIVibrancyEffect *vibrancyEffect = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:blurEffect];
    UIVisualEffectView *vibrancyView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:vibrancyEffect];
    [vibrancyView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    //[vibrancyView.contentView addSubview:s];
    [blurView.contentView addSubview:vibrancyView];



}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chief problem with your code is that you have neglected to give your blur view any size. Therefore it has zero size. Thus you will not see it do anything; it is, in effect, invisible. The most it can blur would be a single pixel behind it, and you are unlikely to notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the frame for your blurView and vibrancyView.

```
blurView.frame = self.view.frame;
vibrancyView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Comment: Actually, no. He doesn't want to make the blur view's frame the same as its superview's _frame_; he wants to make the blur view's frame the same as its superview's _bounds_. (Setting it the same as the superview's frame _might_ work, but only if the frame and bounds happen to be the same, which is usually not the case.)

Comment: @matt I see my mistake now. I wasn't paying attention to the frame size requirement and just pasted from xCode. Thanks